# Código de suma no funciona

Tags: javascript, windows

Tengo que hacer un programa que haga lo siguiente: Realiza un script que pida números hasta que se pulse “cancelar”. Al salir con “cancelar” deberá indicarse la suma total de los números introducidos.
Este es mi código:

```js
var Suma = 0
function Sumar(){

  let número = prompt("Dime un número")
  if(número == "cancelar"){
    alert("Ok")
    document.write(Suma)
  }else{
    let num = parseInt(número)
    var Suma = Suma + num
    Sumar()
  }
}
Sumar()
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando hago el document.write(Suma) me sale undefined.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Esta es una buena primera pregunta, ya que has expuesto el problema de un modo claro y has incluido el código (un [mcve]) para reproducir tu escenario. De todos modos te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para ganar tu primera medalla

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás definiendo cada vez a `Suma` dentro del `else`.

Cambia `var Suma = Suma + num` por `Suma = Suma + num` y funcionará.

```js
var Suma = 0

function Sumar() {

  let número = prompt("Dime un número")
  if (número == "cancelar") {
    alert("Ok")
    document.write(Suma)
  } else {
    let num = parseInt(número)
    Suma = Suma + num
    Sumar()
  }
}
Sumar()
```

---

### Algunas recomendaciones

1. Evita el uso de acentos o caracteres especiales al nombrar tus variables. Podrías tener problemas en un contexto donde la codificación no esté bien definida.
2. Indica con claridad al usuario las acciones que debe realizar. En el mensaje del prompt debería quedar indicado que hay que escribir la palabra cancelar para salir (en mi primera prueba del código ¡tuve que cerrar la pestaña porque no encontraba la salida!).
3. En Javascript puedes también usar el [operador Asignación de suma (`+=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) para agregar el valor del operando derecho a una variable y asignar el resultado a la variable.
4. Cuando creas `num` conviene indicar que en caso de no ser un entero lo convierta en `0`  usando el [operador lógico OR (`|| 0`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), esto evitará que si el usuario escribe un valor no numérico obtengas `NaN`, lo cual haría que el resultado final sea `NaN` en consecuencia (puedes intentar escribiendo varios números y una letra en tu código original para ver a lo que me refiero).

Aplicando estas cuatro recomendaciones, el código quedaría así:

```js
var Suma = 0

function Sumar() {

  let numero = prompt("Dime un número. Escribe cancelar para salir")
  if (numero == "cancelar") {
    alert("Ok")
    document.write(Suma)
  } else {
    let num = parseInt(numero) || 0
    /*
       Podrías también hacer esto:
       Suma += parseInt(numero) || 0
       Así no tendrías que crear una variable num
    */
    Suma += num
    Sumar()
  }
}
Sumar()
```